# AWS Elastic load balancing -Out of Service Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-security-group

I have created my load balancer and added ec2-instance to my load balancer but it marks my instance as out of service. My load balancer and the ec2-instance has the same security group assigned to it.

Security Group: (Inbound traffic and outbound-Type:HTTP, Protocol: TCP, Port range:80, source:0.0.0.0/0)

```
Load balancer  Health Check details:
Ping Protocol : TCP
Ping Port:80
Response timeout:5
Interval:10
Unhealthy Threshold:5
Healthy Threshold:3
```

Also,Tried removing the instance from the aws ELB and added to my elb again but that did'nt work. Can anyone give me any suggestions or help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is your Load Balncer and AWS ELB are they two separate?

Comment: What happen when you put the ip address of your EC2 in a browser? Do you see your application?

Comment: no i tried connecting my ip from browser but it says unable to connect. but i am able to ping to that ip

Comment: Do you have apache configured on your EC2 Instance? What application does it have?

Comment: i am new to this elb. i havent configured apache on my ec2 instance.and  i am using amzon linux ami, ebs volume for glusterfs storage and have installed gluster server on it. do i need iam role  for my instance ??

Comment: If you don't have a website actually running on your EC2 instance yet then none of this is going to work. The ELB is checking to see if the website is actually accessible on the server, it's not just checking if it can ping the server.

Comment: No you don't need IAM role you need to configure your server to listen to Port 80 run this command on the instance sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT and detach and attach the instance and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

load balancer marked the instance as inservice after installing httpd

```
 sudo yum install httpd 
 sudo service httpd start
```